# mySQL query and match entire e-mail address

Tags: mysql

In a mySQL query I use something like this to search for matches

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = keyword
```

When there is an e-mail without a hyphen `-` like `foo@domain.com` and the keyword is `foo` then mySQL easily presents me the correct result.
But when there is a hyphen `-` in the e-mail like `foo-bar@domain.com` and the keyword is `foo-bar` mySQL present me all entries with `foo`. This is also true with `@`.

Is there a workaround avaliable to query and match for an entire e-mail adress including `-` and `@` sign ?

Comment: This looks funny: "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email =:keyword" --- Don't you mean: "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = @keyword"?

Comment: oh thanks - that was take from a PDO binding statement. I removed the `:`

Comment: I still feel like there's something missing from the question. Keywords and fields should match whole email addresses by default. If you're simply comparing two database fields with email addresses, your code should already match the way you need it to.

Comment: Where is this "keyword" coming from? Is it a variable, or another database field, or what?

Comment: keyword is a replacement for a variable `$str` and bound like this `$query->bindValue(':keyword',$str, PDO::PARAM_STR)`

Comment: From the earlier comments, it looks like you only think the SELECT statement is how you have put it in the OP. Have you actually printed it out after you've programmatically substituted the bound values?

Comment: The question is unclear. Post your actual/full code/query along with db schema and example value(s).

Comment: I left the question @Ben seeing no response to my comment, almost 20 mins. prior to this one. You can ping someone/myself directly with the @ symbol if you want, I can't keep staring at this question unless you had to go somewhere which I can understand. Wishing you well with this.

Comment: I think what's missing is what you're using to speak to MySQL. The question looks like you're referring exclusively to MySQL, but judging by more information in the comments, it's a query that's being issued by some other environment that you don't mention. You need to add more information for people to help you with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Asci code for HTML table code

Comment: could you explain this better or give an example ?

Comment: @admo How `HTML table code` can related to this question?